# Can I get the text of notifications in a command line script?

Tags: command-line, notification

There is information which only appears in a notification for an app I'm using (specifically, the open port number in the private internet access app). Super+V will show me the notification from when the app started, so the information has to be laying around somewhere. Anyone know of a way to extract the notification text to use in a script? Some dbus message I can send to get the text perhaps? Some file the desktop stores the notifications in? Or a way to replace the standard notification app with one that could log the info somewhere?

Comment: Notification messages are not saved anywhere by default. Certain apps can listen to  dbus and record those notifications, so technically yes - there is a way via `dbus-monitor` command, or via specific language's dbus API. But remember this - exactly because dbus uses real-time messaging, there's no way to read "history". You can only save and read notifications from time X to time when you stop watching the bus.

Comment: Yep, dbus-monitor works. I've just built a Rube Goldberg set of scripts to background a script that looks for the info in the dbus-monitor output, then start the pia client after I'm sure I'll see the notification. It does work, but it is silly. I edit the startup apps to replace the pia client with my script.

Comment: Alright, looks like you found a solution, right? And it's not that silly to edit startup apps, it's probably marginally easier than writing your own. Let me know if you have any further questions, though. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's doable, here's an example:

```
$ dbus-monitor destination=org.freedesktop.Notifications&
$ notify-send "This is a test...";
```

And the result:

```
    signal time=1668034888.497654 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.21703 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
       string ":1.21703"
    signal time=1668034888.497812 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.21703 serial=4 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
       string ":1.21703"
    method call time=1668034915.205299 sender=:1.21705 -> destination=:1.56 serial=6 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=GetServerInformation
    method call time=1668034915.207146 sender=:1.21705 -> destination=:1.56 serial=7 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
       string "notify-send"
       uint32 0
       string ""
       string "This is a test..."
       string ""
       array [
       ]
       array [
          dict entry(
             string "urgency"
             variant             byte 1
          )
       ]
       int32 -1
```